# Printing powers of numbers and adding them all together

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function obliczTo() {
  var bet = document.forms["oblicz"]["bet"].value;
  var kol = document.forms["oblicz"]["kolejki"].value;

  var bankRoll = bet * Math.pow(2.1, kol)
  document.write('Potrzebujesz: ' + Math.ceil(bankRoll))
}
```

```html
<form name="oblicz" onsubmit="return obliczTo()" method="post" required>
  Bet: <input type="text" name="bet"> Ile kolejek: <input type="text" name="kolejki">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want to print every power in html and add all of them together and print that as bankRoll.
for ex

```
bet = 10
kol = 5
```

in html:

```
21
44.1
92.61
194.481
408.4101

Bank Roll: 760.6011
```

And I want to print each individual output and show their accumulated sum as "Bank Roll".

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How do I print all of the powers 1by1 and then add them to get bankRoll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [geometric series summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) you can simplify your algorithm in the way that you can *directly* calculate the sum of any series without having to step through the individual exponentiation steps:

[image]

where `S` is the total sum, `a` is the starting amount, `q` is the factor and `n` the highest exponent. I modified the formula here slightly: I subtracted the initial amount `a` from it, as you don't seem to want it included in the summation. So you end up with this modified summation formula:

[image]

```js
const geomSum=([a,q,n])=>// (a*(q**(n+1)-1)/(q-1)-a).toFixed((n||6)-1),
                            (a*(q**(n+1)-q)/(q-1)  ).toFixed((n||6)-1),
      res=document.getElementById('res'),
      v=[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'));
function calc(){res.textContent=geomSum(v.map(e=>+e.value));}
document.querySelector('form').oninput=calc;
calc();
```

```html
<form>
 <input name="a" placeholder="start value" value="10"><br>
 <input type="number" name="q" placeholder="factor" value="2.1"><br>
 <input type="number" name="n" placeholder="exponent" value="5">
</form><br><br>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, note that JavaScript numbers are floating point, and floating-point arithmetic with fractions is often imprecise. For example:

```js
Math.pow(2.1, 4)
// should be 19.4481
// actually yields 19.448100000000004
```

`Math.ceil` rounds up to the nearest integer, which won't work for what we want here - `Math.ceil(19.448100000000004)` gives `20`.

Here's one (kinda hacky) way of dealing with it that should work for our use case, as long as `kol` doesn't get very high:

```js
const round = n => Number(n.toPrecision(12))
```

Now, you need to *loop* through numbers `1..kol`, printing and summing as you go. You can use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement) for this.

```js
const form = document.forms.oblicz
const output = document.querySelector('#output')

const round = n => Number(n.toPrecision(12))

const clearOutput = () => output.textContent = ''
const appendLineToOutput = str => output.textContent += `\n${str}`

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  
  clearOutput()

  const bet = Number(form.bet.value)
  const kol = Number(form.kolejki.value)

  let bankRoll = 0

  for (let i = 1; i <= kol; ++i) {
    const val = round(bet * Math.pow(2.1, i))

    appendLineToOutput(val)

    bankRoll = round(bankRoll + val)
  }

  appendLineToOutput(`Potrzebujesz: ${bankRoll}`)
})
```

```html
<form name="oblicz" required>
  Bet: <input type="text" name="bet" value="10"> Ile kolejek: <input type="text" name="kolejki" value="5">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<pre><output id="output"></output></pre>
```

Note that I've used `document.querySelector` and `textContent` here, not `document.write`. `document.write` is generally considered to be deprecated, because it clears the entire document if the page is already loaded.